# UITable view interface builder creation

Tags: ios, xcode

I am building an app using storyboard. I have added a table view to my view controller, chose static cells, and custom, insertea a title and some pictures. I have also linked each row to a view controller, with modal segue. But I want to be able to add, delete, and reorder the rows. So I added the codes. The only thing is that I can not connect the table view to the codes. If I connect the data source, and run the project I see just an empty table view. So, is there a way to create the table view using interface builder, and just a few codes? otherwise if there are to much codes everything gets messed up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Connect `delegate` and `datasource` to `ViewController` icon in your Storyboard. Then add `UITableviewdelegate` and `UITableviewdatasource` in view controller code. When you connect and do this, then tableview will search its delegate and datasource methods in your code and you will get the output which you expect.

Comment: i can't because I can only choose static cell property if the view is in a table view controller, and I can't connect the table view controller to the projectviewcontrller. if I use a normal view, I can't use static cells

Answer (score 0):

If you want to add, delete and reorder the rows, you can't use static layouts, because those operations make the table view not static!

You will have to implement it using datasource methods and dynamic prototypes. It won't be too difficult. You can still build each type of cell in the storyboard, you can have multiple prototypes with different reuse identifiers.

Comment: yes, but even if I modify the cells on interface builder (add pictures, size them), when I run the app it shows a normal list (the NSArray I have set), and not the interface builder version with the code functions

Comment: another thing is that it also removes the custom segues linked to each row

Comment: For your first comment, you are probably not reusing cells properly. Please include your cellForRowAtIndexPath code in your question. For the second, if you need a custom segue you can set it up directly from the view controller, and call it in didSelectRow.